# What is the difference between these two code snippets?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Both display `23`.  But what is the difference between the two?

code-1

```
main()
{
    int *ar[10];

    **(ar+0) = 23;
    printf( "%d", **(ar+0) );

    return 0;
}
```

Code-2

```
main()
{
    int *ar[10];

    *(ar+0) = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    **(ar+0) = 23;   
    printf( "%d", **(ar+0) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice homework question ;)

Comment: In first code `**(ar+0) = 23;` call [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: What do you think? What happens when you run them? Why do you think one of them potentially causes your computer to crash & burn?

Comment: Not homework..just me bro ;)

Comment: Instead of `ar+0`, write `ar[0]`.

Comment: Actually, in Win8.1 console, both assignments work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a program accessing illegal pointer to pointer not crash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852212/why-does-a-program-accessing-illegal-pointer-to-pointer-not-crash)

Comment: The Windows 8.1 console has absolutely nothing to do with it, and the behaviour of the first snippet is most definitely undefined. It is perfectly valid `C++` behaviour if the program uploads your harddrive contents to the internet in the background. While circumventing your firewall.

Comment: k. thx for all the answers guys. :)

Comment: The proposed duplicate question (Why does a program accessing illegal pointer to pointer not crash) is not a good duplicate; it is dealing with an initialized pointer, not an unininitialized pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
int *ar[10];
**(ar+0) = 23;
```

This is *undefined behavior* (you assign `23` to some "random" memory) because you don't have allocated space for this `23` int element (`ar` is array of pointers).

---

<strike>int *ar[10];
    *(ar+0) = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf( "%d", **(ar+0) );</strike>

Allocates memory for an `int` at the first `ar` element, but *should* print "garbage", as this `int` is not initialized.

As the question was edited and the initialization is added: the second version is perfectly fine (if `malloc` succeeds).

---

`*(ar+0)` is the same as `ar[ 0 ]`

Comment: please update your answer -- the question has been updated in an incompatible way.

Comment: Note: The implementation is only file if the `malloc()` succeeds.

Comment: Ok, so just to be perfectly clear...my book is showing me a (*int) cast for malloc.  Is this really not good practice?  Is it a C version difference? say, ANSI C vs C99 or something?

Comment: @DaveBlack - sorry, I'm not sure about this one, I've (almost) never used `malloc`, as I use `C++` primary. You could as unwind for this and try to understand the link, he quoted.

Comment: @Kiril - Yeah, thx.  I peeked around and got the answer.  Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is undefined behavior. It defines `a` to be an array of 10 pointers to integers, but doesn't initialize the pointers before using the first one (`a[0]`) in a write. This is undefined behavior.

The second one first sets the pointer to the return value of `malloc()` (with a [really bad cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)) so it has a better chance of not invoking UB. Of course, if the allocation fails and returns `NULL`, it's undefined behavior all over again.

Comment: IS this better?:  main()
{

 int *ar[10];
 
 ar[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *ar[0] = 5;
 printf( "%d", *ar[0] );

 return 0;
}

Comment: @DaveBlack Did you click the link, to read about casting `malloc()`'s return value? No, I don't think it's acceptable. And yes, the variant without the cast is of course better. It'd be even better to have `ar[0] = malloc(sizeof *ar[0]);` to remove the repeat of the type. Also, one seldom really allocates that little memory.

Comment: Yes, I read it.  TY.  I am learning from 'Understanding and Using C Pointers' by Oreilly.  Their example used the (int*) cast.

Answer (score 0):

Both samples first specify an array of ten integer pointers.

The first sample then goes on to write to a value to the first pointer -- without even allocating it. This is undefined behaviour and will most likely segfault.

The second sample allocates memory for the first pointer, and then writes a value there. It is has perfectly defined behaviour. That is, If the `malloc()` succeeds, which you need to check.