# Fgets only returning '\n' char

Tags: c, string, char, fgets

I'm trying to use fgets to get a line from stdin. Here's my code

```
char* FENString;
printf("Enter FEN Key: ");
fgets(FENString, 50, stdin);
```

FENString only has one char, and that's the new line character. I've tried looking for help and haven't found anything, does anyone know why this is happening?

---

It's very important to make sure that all variables have some sort of memory allocated to it, at least in some point of its lifecycle. The issue here was that the char pointer didn't have any sort of memory allocated to it. Something that could've fixed it is `malloc`ing the FENString, or perhaps changing the declaration to something like `char FENString[50];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a program accessing illegal pointer to pointer not crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852212/why-does-a-program-accessing-illegal-pointer-to-pointer-not-crash) Not an exact duplicate, but the explanation for the underlying behavior is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having Undefined behavior  by providing a unintialized pointer to `fgets`. Allocate memory of `>=50` size to `FENString` and then pass it to `fgets`.

#### Solution-1

```
char* FENString;
FENString = malloc(50);
if( FENString == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in malloc");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Enter FEN Key: ");
if( fgets(FENString, 50, stdin) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
    exit(1);
}
// Work with FENString;
...
free(FENString);
```

#### Solution-2

Simply have a `char` array like this `char FENString[50]`; Then the code would be

```
char FENString[50];
printf("Enter FEN Key: ");
if( fgets(FENString, sizeof FENString, stdin) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n","Error in input");
    exit(1);
}
// Work with FENString
```

<sup>Instead of `50` here `sizeof FENString` although it does the same thing this is much better towards a good maintainable solution. In case you letter change it, you don't have to search and replace `50` it will be automaticlaly done due to use of `sizeof`.(Peter points out)</sup>

Comment: @user3386109.: Thanks for the edit. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: In the "solution-2", it is possible to use `sizeof(FENString)` rather than `50` in the `fgets()` call.   This ensures the correct value is passed regardless of what dimension `FENString` is defined with  (so, if the dimension of the array is changed, it is not necessary to remember to change the length specified to `fgets()`).

Comment: @Peter.: Yes that's a nice pick. I edited. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Peter.: Added explanation along with it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
char* FENString;
printf("Enter FEN Key: ");
fgets(FENString, 50, stdin);
```

`FENString` is a **character pointer** and  before putting any data into it, `FENString` should have *valid memory space to store something into it*. But in your case `FENString` doesn't point to valid address which is the issue.

To resolve this you can take `FENString` either as a character buffer like

```
char FENString[1024] = {};
```

or allocate memory dynamically for `FENString` like

```
char* FENString = malloc(sizeof(*FENString) * MAX_BUF_SIZE); /* define the MAX_BUF_SIZE, instead of magic number like 50 use macro */
/* Do error handling malloc() */
if(FENString == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Now store the user input into dynamically created array by calling `fgets()` . For example

```
if(fgets(FENString, MAX_BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL){
    /* fgets is success, but if fgets store the \n at the end of buffer if its read */
    /* to remove trailing \n char use strcspn() */
    FENString[strcspn(FENString, "\n")] = 0;
}
```